# How to change default "Change-Id" select in eclipse Git plugin

Tags: eclipse, egit

in our project Change-id is mandatory for commit. 
righ now we use to click the button manully.
but some time developer will forgot to click
while committing via eclipse "Change-id for gerrit code review" should select automatically for all the commit.
is there any option to do this?
can we automate the change-id selection via setting?
please help me on this.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Git configuration `gerrit.createchangeid` to `true`. With this, it should automatically be added.

As with other Git configuration, this can be set in the repository (`.git/config`) or the user configuration (`.gitconfig` in the user directory).

Answer (score 1):

With this command, I was able to activate the automatically set of Change-Id:

```
git config --global gerrit.createchangeid true
```

Then I had to restart Eclipse.

When I added it in the .config file, Eclipse immediately complained about invalid config file...